# multiple file upload using same form but different input fields using jquery php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have searched for this thing on stack overflow, I was unable to find a relevant answer to my issue. Please have a look at the code I am using to fetch data and throw it to a php file and upload files to the respective folders and store their link to database. But I am not able to store data. It shows "unable to upload data."

**Jquery file:**

```
$(document).on('click','#modalMenu', function(){
        var pagename = $("#pagename").val();
        var page = 'modalMenu';
        var menuname = $("#menuname").val();
        var nav = $("#nav").val();
        var content = CKEDITOR.instances['content'].getData();

        var form_data = new FormData();
        var file_data = $('#file').get(0).files[0];
        var logo = $('#logo').get(0).files[0];
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        form_data.append('logo', logo);
        form_data.append('pagename', pagename);
        form_data.append('menuname', menuname);
        form_data.append('content', content);
        form_data.append('nav', nav);
        form_data.append('page', page);
        $.ajax({
                    url: 'insert.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
                    //dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: form_data,                         
                    method: 'POST',
                    success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    location.reload();
                }

         });
    });
```

**form on some page**

```
<form  method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="javascript:;">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Page Name" id="pagename" name="pagename" style="max-width:25%; display:inline" />
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nav Name" id="nav" name="nav" style="max-width:25%; display:inline" />
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Menu Name" id="menuname" name="menuname" style="max-width:25%; display:inline" />
                    <input type="file" name="logo" id="logo" title="Menu Logo" class="form-control"  style="max-width:20%; display:inline"/>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Summery Part.. Please make it crisp" id="content" name="content" style="max-width:30%; display:inline" />
                        <script>
                                var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( "content", {
                                uiColor: "#ffffff",
                                filebrowserBrowseUrl : "../ckeditor-ckfinder-integration/ckfinder/ckfinder.html",
                                filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : "../ckeditor-ckfinder-integration/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images",
                                filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl : "../ckeditor-ckfinder-integration/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash",
                                filebrowserUploadUrl : "../ckeditor-ckfinder-integration/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files",
                                filebrowserImageUploadUrl : "../ckeditor-ckfinder-integration/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images",
                                filebrowserFlashUploadUrl : "../ckeditor-ckfinder-integration/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash"
                            });
                            CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor, "../" );
                        </script>
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="form-control"  style="max-width:25%; display:inline"/>
                    <input type="submit" id="modalMenu" name="modalMenu" class="btn btn-success" align="right" value="+" />
                    </form>
```

**insert.php file**

```
$pageName=$_POST['page'];
     if($pageName=='modalMenu'){

$pagename=$_POST['pagename'];
$menuname=$_POST['menuname'];
$nav=$_POST['nav'];
$content=$_POST['content'];

$error=$_FILES['file']['error'];
    if($error!=0)
    {
    echo "Error with File data Upload. File not uploaded, it seems the file is not selected or there is some error with the file or the server seems busy, try later.
    We will redirect you back to the dashboard. Please wait..";
    }
    else
    {
    $fname=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $ftype=$_FILES['file']['type'];
    $fsize=$_FILES['file']['size'];
    $ftname=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $target="../modalMenu/$fname";

    $ans=move_uploaded_file($ftname,$target);
    if($ans)
    {
                        $error=$_FILES['logo']['error'];
                            if($error!=0)
                            {
                            echo "Error with Image Data Upload. File not uploaded, it seems the file is not selected or there is some error with the file or the server seems busy, try later.
                            We will redirect you back to the dashboard. Please wait..";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            $logo_name=$_FILES['logo']['name'];
                            $logo_type=$_FILES['logo']['type'];
                            $logo_size=$_FILES['logo']['size'];
                            $logo_tname=$_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'];
                            $target2="../modalMenu/$fname";

                            $ans=move_uploaded_file($ftname,$target2);
                            if($ans)
                            {

                            //save info to database
                            $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                            mysql_select_db("rcg_db",$con) or die (mysql_error());
                            $target=addslashes($target);

                                $query="INSERT INTO `modalmenu`(`pagename`, `nav`, `menuname`, `menulogo`, `content`, `readmore`) VALUES ('$pagename','$nav','$menuname','$target' ,'$content','$target2');";
                                $n=mysql_query($query);

                                if($n==1)
                                {
                                    echo "File upload successful! Data is added. Please wait while page reloads";

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                echo "File not uploaded, server seems busy, try later. We will redirect you back to the dashboard. Please wait..";

                                }
                            }
                            }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "File not uploaded, server seems busy, try later. We will redirect you back to the dashboard. Please wait.";

    }

    }

}
```

Thank you in advance. In case I am not using a good way of coding please do recommend and resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to send the ajax into PHP but PHP cant save it?

Ill give you an example

jQuery

```
$(#modalMenu).on('click',function(){
    var fname = $("#fname").val();
    var lname = $("#lname").val();
    var age = $("#age").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'insert.php', //point to server-side PHP script
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data:{
            "fname" : fname,
            "lname" : lname,
            "age" : age,
            "save" : true
        },
        success: function(yes){
            if(yes.success == true){
                window.location.reload(true);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

PHP

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO beneficiary (fname, lname, age)
    VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$age')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo json_encode(array(
    "success" => true,
));
```

Comment: Sir, I wasn't asking for storing data using ajax call. I am able to do that using simple ajax call. The issue comes when I am trying to upload two files from two input fields as shown in above codes.

Answer (score 0):

refer the below link, i think this is useful for you
http://www.codexworld.com/upload-multiple-images-using-jquery-ajax-php/

Comment: Sir, I am trying to upload one image form one field and one .pdf file from the other field. and with that I do have few written data to be uploaded. I went through the link and found that the code showed the way to upload multiple files one after another, and all are image files. I here want that the user select one image, one pdf file, write some text in other fields and then on one click the user could upload the files and move the data to database.

Comment: @VikashMishra hi mate wat is the solution you are following.